# Convert package from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: python, importerror

I have just purchased a book to learn Python and it came with a custom python package (including all the *.py files), I installed this package using

```
python setup.py install
```

Now because I have 64 bit version of python installed, so when I got this error -

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I realized that I need to somehow convert the package from 32bit to 64 bit. But this is as far as I know, could someone please point me to a way to do this conversion. I have all the source files with me.

Comment: check if there is a 64 bit version of the package , i.e installer for 64 bit version. The package can't be converted like that.

Comment: There is no way to convert the 32-bit libraries to 64-bit. If you really have the source files, you could try to compile the library using a 64-bit compiler. However, the easiest solution probably is to install a 32-bit version of Python.

Comment: @Callidior yes I have all the source files, would you please let me know how to compile them to 64 bit version.